# What (un)templating engines allow to read DOM read back to JSON?

Tags: javascript, templates

Most every templating engines take some template and some data and evaluate/render/compile/precompile them together into an output that is either a string or browser DOM/HtmlElements.

```
data + template [templating engine]-> resultString/resultDom
```

I am looking for a "de/untemplating engine" allowing for the inverse

```
resultDom + template [untemplating engine]-> data
```

I would expect that some of the zillions of templating engines out there are capable of this step, right? which are they?

Also in case it matters the data output of such a un-templating should ideally be to JSON/-in-Browser Javascript-objects and the input is most likely a Browser DOM Model of HTML data.

Comment: I believe what you looking for is `web scraping` technique . So any scraping frameworks would do.

Comment: @Andrey thanks for suggesting that keyword. I will look into if that is it. My use case is that I have data that using a template engine I transform into HTML. Then however the Browser/Javascript DOM modifies it, the modified data should server as an update to the data.